# Android Studıo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My error;

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp/com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a
> null object reference

My code;

```
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT_CODE = 1023 ;
    TextView fullName,email,phone,verifyMsg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;
    Button resendCode;
    Button resetPassLocal,changeProfileImage;
    FirebaseUser user;
    ImageView profileImage;
    StorageReference storageReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email    = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        resetPassLocal = findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordLocal);

        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        changeProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.changeProfile);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        StorageReference profileRef = storageReference.child("users/"+fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/profile.jpg");
        profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profileImage);
            }
        });

        resendCode = findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
        verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);


        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
            verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Verification Email Has been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("tag", "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }




        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    phone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
                    fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                    email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

                }else {
                    Log.d("tag", "onEvent: Document do not exists");
                }
            }
        });


        resetPassLocal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText resetPassword = new EditText(v.getContext());

                final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password ?");
                passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Enter New Password > 6 Characters long.");
                passwordResetDialog.setView(resetPassword);

                passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // extract the email and send reset link
                        String newPassword = resetPassword.getText().toString();
                        user.updatePassword(newPassword).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // close
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.create().show();

            }
        });

        changeProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open gallery
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.EditProfile.class);
                i.putExtra("fullName",fullName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("phone",phone.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
//

            }
        });


    }


.

    public void logout(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();//logout
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.Login.class));
        finish();
    }


}
```

I wanna start my app using the firebase database but ı cant do that when ı start the app; my app is crashing.

don't read;

I'm writing because I can't post my questionI'm writing because I can't post my question

Comment: userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); here you need to check if null or not

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Seems your trying to access a current user does not exist.

**Possible Solution**

Try checking if user is signed in else should not run the code which needs the current user confirmation.

Here is your refined code.

```
....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
    ....
    resendCode = findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
    verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);

    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        
         verifyUser();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("tag", "The user is not authenticated");
    }

}
```

**verifyUser Method**

```
public void verifyUser()
{
    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
        verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Verification Email Has been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("tag", "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }




    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                phone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
                fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

            }else {
                Log.d("tag", "onEvent: Document do not exists");
            }
        }
    });


    resetPassLocal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText resetPassword = new EditText(v.getContext());

            final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password ?");
            passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Enter New Password > 6 Characters long.");
            passwordResetDialog.setView(resetPassword);

            passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // extract the email and send reset link
                    String newPassword = resetPassword.getText().toString();
                    user.updatePassword(newPassword).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // close
                }
            });

            passwordResetDialog.create().show();

        }
    });

    changeProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open gallery
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.EditProfile.class);
            i.putExtra("fullName",fullName.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("phone",phone.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
```

Hope it solves the problem.